# Clone a control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

What's the best way to clone a control in Silverlight (including it's children)?

UPDATE

Is there a better way in Silverlight 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a great thread](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/1730.aspx) about serializing and deserializing objects in Silverlight 1.1.

As for a "best way," I'd say it would definitely be caching the xaml for the control and calling createFromXaml on it.